# Why is Vista continuously hitting my web server?

Tags: windows-vista, webserver

On our home network there's my computer (XP) and the mom's computer (Vista).  I've noticed this weekend that her computer (I confirmed the IP) is hitting the web server on my computer about every five minutes.  It's just a GET request for "/" and that's it.

I've run Microsoft Defender and it found nothing.  I'm running McAfee now to see if it's a virus.

Is there anything besides a virus that would cause a Vista machine to repeatedly request a local web server?

Comment: Call me crazy but before asking here, you should have asked you mom. 
Your mom could be a famous hacker testing her latest creation, and you just painted a target on her. Even the fact that it is your mom's, sister's or step-dad's  computer, is information irrelevant to the question you are asking. Although chances are it's Vista running some sort of "helpful" network discovery routine :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out what is making the requests to your server go download [Microsoft/SysInternals Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  It is a nice process monitor tool.  By default it will tell you a lot more than you really want.  I would set it to just monitor network activity and if your server is getting hit every 5 minutes it should be hard to track down the culprit.